# Clarity on Vagrant usage and provisioning tool

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Ok, so I'm a bit late jumping onto the Vagrant band-wagon, but figured it's about time I did.

**Brief background:** I've been a freelance developer for quite some time now developing solutions based on Magento and Drupal, and have finally gathered enough demand to warrant the need to build up a team. Previously, whenever I started development on any new project, I use to clone a preconfigured base VM in Virtualbox, and use that. Of course there were still configurations to do on it until I could start with actual development. Every project's web files therefore all resided inside `/var/www/projectname` on an Ubuntu VM.

Now I've read up on **why** I should be Vagrant, especially considering that I now have a team of 4 developers working with me, but I would appreciate any feedback on the following questions I have:

*Moderator note: I know this isn't exactly asking a programming question, so please advise if this could be turned into a wiki, as I'm sure that feedback into this will help someone just like me.*

I am still reading through the Vagrant docs, so please be kind...noob questions ahead!

1. I now work on a Mac. Does it matter if I use Parallels, and another developer uses VirtualBox on Windows if we need to share or collaborate on projects?
2. When I issue the command, `vagrant up` for an existing project, will it start the VM up as I would in VirtualBox or will it recreate the VM?
3. Is the command `vagrant halt` the same issuing `sudo poweroff` in Ubuntu, for example?
4. I currently use PhpStorm and its SFTP feature for project files synchronization with the option to exclude certain files on the remote server (VM) from being imported and sync'ed...will I be able to specify the same using Vagrant folder sharing?
5. Could I easily zip or archive a Vagrant VM, move it to a file server, and then "re-import" when and if needed? (example bug fixes, or new feature enhancements)
6. What do we use to easily provision VMs for common projects? Should we being using *Puppet, Chef, Puphpet or Salt*? I've seen that *[Puphpet](http://puphpet.com)* provides a nice GUI to create a `vagrantfile` which I'm sure once generated, we could customize for future projects. At a very basic level, we need to ensure that certain applications are installed onto the server (zip, phpmyadmin, OpenSSL, etc.), certain PHP settings, PHP and PEAR modules, and Apache settings. I already have base VMs set up as I'd like them for both Magento projects as well as Drupal projects.

**EDIT:** I should also add that I use to enable *Host Adapter* in VirtualBox (on Windows), configure the VHost inside Ubuntu, and then update my host machine's `hosts` file with something like `192.168.56.3   drupalsite1.dev`. So I'm unsure if Port Forwarding would be better to use? I'm not very clued up on that I must admit.

Like i said - noob questions! However, I would really appreciate any feedback on these questions. My deepest thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you are asking is subjective so common sense and experience are the best tools.

1. I recommend all team members use the same provider (parallels isn't officially supported) and virtualbox is readily available. The base boxes, by provider, could have slight variances, you never know.
2. Vagrant will start the vm similarly but vagrant also does other things like configuration the network, hostname, shared folders, etc. Not quite the same. The big power lies in the capability to be able to teardown the environment and bring it back in a cleanly provisioned state.
3. Basically, yes.
4. Yes, your vagrant VMs are just like your own mini cloud. You would interact the servers similar to the way you'd interact with external boxes.
5. Yes, the simple answer is that it's called packaging and you can share the resultant .box. However, it's good practice to keep the base box and provisioning scripts under CM so you can rebuild and modify as needed.
6. For provisioners, I think it is dependent upon your experience and your familiarity with the provisioner language and how much you want to invest in learning them. Look through the provisioner support and see what fits your need and budget. Chef has a very steep learning curve, in my experience, but also has a lot of thought built in. Most provisioners have wide libraries of available installation "scripts".

The host adapter can be handled identically in vagrant.

Learn by doing, I recommend going down the table of contents (navbar) of the vagrant docs and trying each step where it makes sense. Then make your decisions.

That is my 2 cents. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mike! I'm actually reading other articles that have shed more light on the the subject so every piece of information helps... even asking experts here on SO.

Comment: Regarding #2, my main concern is that we'll obviously be working on any one project over a few days or weeks. So I wouldn't want to start up a VM only to realise that all the previous day's work had been overwritten or deleted. Is this even possible?

Comment: Regarding #4, my understanding is that the shared folder will basically download everything specified in the remote directory? Just thought that there was maybe some Ruby script for vagrant to exclude certain remote folders instead of pulling everything or letting an IDE handle it

Comment: @maGz definitely get in and crank up some vms. easiest way is to 1- find a box on vagrantcloud.com with your target/familiar OS   2- `vagrant init hashicorp/precise64` (for example)   3- `vagrant up`  4- start adding some shell provisioning then `destroy`ing and `up`ing.

Comment: @maGz #2 the vagrant box will stick around until you `vagrant destroy` it (or tinker with the filesystem). however, these boxes are meant to be a bit more transient so I recommend you have a repeatable way to get back to that state.

Comment: Thanks again Mike! I agree that that's the best way to learn. Of course time is an issue, hence asking here, but that's no excuse!

Comment: #4 yes, by default it would be synced. so create a new empty folder and deploy into that as shown here `config.vm.synced_folder "deploy/", "/srv/website"`

Comment: I feel your pain, probably why we are all here! I recommend you don't dive into provisioner tech yet then. Vagrant is much simpler than most of the provisioners, IMHO. Good luck!

Comment: My sincerest thanks Mike! You've been very helpful... and patient!  I'll play around with just vagrant and make the jump to using puphpet (it seems a lot simpler and less time consuming than hand crafting other provisioning scripts). But I think I feel a bit more comfortable diving in now a bit more armed. Cheers!